# Google Analytics - not measuring all sales data correctly

Tags: google-analytics, magento2

We've discovered a problem with our Google Analytics. We discovered it missed ±15% of our orders daily.

Here is the problem.

- A customer goes to checkout
- In the checkout they select a payment method and get redirected to the website of their bank.
- They don't wait for the success page (/checkout/success)
- Because they don't wait for the success page GA does not register this sale.

Does anyone know of a way to 'give-back' orders from Magento 2 to GA? This would at least make our Conversion % and Revenue numbers correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a server-to-server call. For example with PayPal you can use Instant Payment Notification (IPN). It is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/

Sending purchase hit from server to Analytics you can obtain 100% of transaction in Google Analytics.